# How can I both use MathTime Pro 2 and newtxmath?

Tags: math-mode, mtpro, newtxmath

I would like to use both the `mtpro2` and `newtxmath` packages in a single document and be able to choose which one to use.
I would like for example to be able to show the following integral in both ways in the same `math-mode` enviroment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
%\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\begin{document}
\[ \int x^2 dx \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it just for showing the difference?

Comment: Basically for general use.The integral is just an example so I can see which command I must use to change it's style. To be able to use both styles in the same document and choose between them.

Comment: Why? That is, it will make your document inconsistent which is usually a bad thing. Unless, of course, you are writing about differences in the way maths is typeset.

Comment: Unfortunately `mtpro2` and `newtx` do so many changes to the default settings that's impossible to make them live together. In any case `\int` will be taken from just one font in one and the same formula. It's not just a question of “commands”, as it involves deep settings for math.

Comment: @egreg I didn't know about these details and It seems that it doesn't worth spending so much time on something that will hardly make any difference.
But thanks anyway for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, `mtpro2` and `newtxmath` act very deep in the settings for math fonts and symbols, with incompatible changes. It can be possible to make up things so that some symbols are taken from `mtpro2` while the general setup is `newtxmath` (or conversely).

However, making them coexist in one and the same document is impossible or, in any case, *very* difficult. Not a task I would confront with.

Math symbols require a sort of table lookup and switching between those two families would require writing code for switching the tables: a huge amount of code, requiring deep study of both packages.